# Safari Browser div collapsing height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

On this page http://bit.ly/202URGh, when I click on Book Size (Second row icons) and then click on Book type (First row icons), the image collapses into the other div.

I have added clearfix, but that seems to have had no effect. This seems to be a problem only in Safari on Mac. Other browsers work fine.

Can someone help. My problem is compounded because I don't have a Mac to test.

Answer (score 0):

I understood the source of the problem. Issue was because I was trying to get the height of image dynamically. Safari (and webkit based browsers) do not seem to support dynamic height computation. Jquery was returning the height as zero and hence the div was collapsing.